# How to read a 200 MHz signal using FPGA

Tags: fpga

I am beginner in FPGAs was looking for an FPGA to read and process a 200MHz digital signal and then output it from another pin, but i am not sure what spec should i be looking for to know if the FPGA can read such signal or not

Answer (score 4):

The keywords you need are "transciever": the general term for hardware that communicates with the off-chip world.

And specifically "SERDES": serial-deserial. If you have bits coming in at 200MHZ this will allow you to process them more conveniently as *bytes*, at 1/8 or 1/10 the speed.

You may also need to know what LVDS and 8b/10b are, depending on what your signal actually is.

Comment: If the question is complete and they really only need to transfer the data as-is to another pin, SERDES might be overkill. No reason for byte processing if you never interpret the data anyway. Just having the FPGA tooling setup the SERDES would trivialize the sampling problem, of course.

Comment: Are the transceivers found in any I/O port of the FPGA or are there special ports for them ?

Comment: It depends - a quick check of the Spartan-6 documentation says it can route to any, but you need to check the datasheet for the specific part you're planning to use. There is no substitute for reading the docs!

Comment: Thank you so much sir ! , I am not very familiar with the rules here but if you can please refer to me that datasheet and at what section where i can search for that information i will be really thankful as i am still new to reading these types of docs

Comment: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds160.pdf section "Input/Output"

Answer (score 2):

By definition: if you want to read a 200MHz signal you need a 400MHz clock, *unless* that signal is already synchronous to some clock you could use to run the FPGA.

The core specification in this case is the maximum frequency for the internal clocks (speed grade). Density is relevant to the complexity of your processing pipeline (at that frequency you *want* to pipeline).

Other than that check that the FPGA can handle the *physical* signal format, i.e. has the relevant transceivers (and maybe some required SERDES); 200 MHz is a little high to be a simple LVCMOS signal so you need to check the exact format the source supplies.

Comment: If I have an external clock that is synchronous to the data, Can i connect that clock to any pin or are there specified pins where i can put the clock through them(and how should i know which pins supports high clocks), as for the data with that high frequency, Can any I/O pin be used as an input to that type of data ? ( Its is a normal Square wave format Polar NRZ)

Comment: There are dedicated pin for synchronous clocks, and usually at least a couple of external clocks are available. As for the I/O type it depends on the specific part, different I/O banks have different capabilities. Polar NRZ is a straight digital signal so you shouldn't have issues unless the levels are strange

Comment: Thanks so much sir!, one final question can you tell me what is the spec where i can know the max frequency a normal I/O pin can support please ?

Answer (score 0):

Most FPGAs and many CPLDs brought out  the last 15 years or so have Double Data Rate (DDR) capability on their I/O pins.

This is some dedicated pin circuitry to sample input levels or drive output levels on both the rising and falling edge of a logic clock.

So your logic I/O circuit can use a 200 MHz logic clock and still sample your 200 MHz waveform twice per waveform period. The rest of the circuit must accept 2 input sample bits per logic clock.

Using DDR, your logic output circuit can run from a 100 MHz clock and provide 2 output bits per logic clock. Or it could run at 200 MHz. It depends on the speed capability of the FPGA you will use.

You'll find plenty of well-written text explaining DDR I/O on the Internet, including FPGA manufacturers' application notes.